# How to addClass() or removeClass when input change()

Tags: jquery

This way dosent work. I'm trying to get input pass2 to compare the value with the input pass when it change. It is not triggering.

jquery

```
$( "#pass2" ).change(function() {
if ( ($("#pass2").val()) != ($("#pass").val()) ) {
    $(".pass2").addClass("has-error");
} else {
    $(".pass2").removeClass("has-error");
}   
});
```

html

```
Pass:
<input id="pass" type="text" name="pass" value="" />
Pass again:
<span class="pass2"><input id="pass2" type="text" name="pass2" value="" /></span>
```

Comment: What error you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check here

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvt85s8v/) it will work fine with `keyup` event, you can there use `change`, but keyup is more useful as per your requirement..

Answer (score 1):

The [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event only fires when loses focus from the text input so use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) or [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event instead to trigger immediately.

```
$( "#pass2" ).on('input', function() {
    if ( ($("#pass2").val()) != ($("#pass").val()) ) {
        $(".pass2").addClass("has-error");
    } else {
        $(".pass2").removeClass("has-error");
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the confirm password in `onblur` event. To do this you need to bind a function for `onblur` event in `pass2` id. And of-course when you call `addClass('has-error')`, then you should remove class `has-success`, otherwise when you are trying for multiple time, your expected result will not appeared.
**N.B:** Additionally you need to check that both fields are not empty as if both fields are being empty result's true.

```js
function checkPass(){
 if($("#pass2").val()!='' && $("#pass").val()!=''){
    if ( ($("#pass2").val()) != ($("#pass").val()) ) {
          $(".pass2").addClass("has-error");
          $(".pass2").addClass("has-success");
          console.log("has-error");// for testing purpose we print it
      } else {
          $(".pass2").removeClass("has-error");
          $(".pass2").addClass("has-succes");
          console.log("has-success"); // for testing purpose we print it
      }
    }else{
          console.log("password field can not be empty");
          // here you can show alert or error msg as you want.
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Pass:
<input id="pass" type="text" name="pass" value="" />
Pass again:
<span class="pass2"><input id="pass2" onblur="checkPass()" type="text" name="pass2" value="" /></span>
```

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ataur63/8hv9xa8o/) also.